# How do I update data on SQLite Database using HTML

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to allow users to update the information that they have provided by clicking the edit icon on my html webpage, but I am unsure on how to start.

[image]

Update:

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('editclaims/<int:id>', views.editclaims, name='editclaims'),
]
```

> views.py

```
def editclaims(request,id):
  context = initialize_context(request)
  user = context['user']
  getclaims = SaveClaimForm.objects.get(id=id)
  return render(request, 'editclaims.html',{'SaveClaimForm':getclaims, 'user':user})
```

> editclaims.html

```html
{% extends "Login/layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
<title>Update Claim {{claims.id}} </title>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form method=POST action="editclaims/{{getclaims.id}}">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Name: </td>
        <td><input id="name" type="text" name="name_field" value = "{{user.name}}" readonly ></td>
        <td>Email: </td>
        <td><input id="email" type="text" name="email_field" value="{{ user.email }}" readonly></td>
        <td>Claim Amount: </td>
        <td><input id="claim" type="number" name="claim_field" required min="0.01" step=".01" value="{{claims.claim}}"></td>
      
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

After doing this the site returns a TemplateDoesNotExist Error.

Comment: and were is HTML? `Edit` should open page similar to `Add` but with filled `input`s in HTML.

Comment: `Edit` similar to `View` should get `name` (or simpler ID) to get data from database.

Comment: So I should create a html that is similar to my NewClaim (Add)?

Comment: yes, you should create HTML and function `edit` similar to `NewClaim` and `ViewClaims`. It should get `name` or `email` (or better `ID`) to get data from database and it should send it (with `ID`)  to HTML which should use `<input>` to display it and edit it. And it should send it (with `ID`) back to fucntion `Edit` to save it to database - similar to `NewClaim` but it should use `ID` to get old value from database, update these value using values from HTML, and save it.

Comment: I have updated the question, but I'm having issues as it returns a TemplateDoesNotExists. @furas

Comment: did you create create HTML template? Did you put it in correct folder? Documetation for Django should describe it.

Comment: Yes I placed the editclaims.html in the same folder (templates\Login) .Could you point me to the right direction in the documentation?

Comment: do you have other templates in `templates\Login` ? As for me it should be rather in `templates` or you may have to load as `Login/editclaims.html` BTW: now I see in template you have `"Login/layout.html"` so it can confirm that you should use `Login/editclaims.html`

Comment: So just to confirm the urlpatterns should be updated to Login/editclaims.html

Comment: not `urlpattern` but `return render(request, 'Login/editclaims.html')`

Comment: Apologies I forgotten to update my views.py. It is working now, I will post the answer with reference to your guidance.

Comment: After submitting the new data on my html, it returns page not found. The path is http://localhost:8000/editclaims/

Comment: it is page to editing data and it needs number `data ID` (row number) to get data from database - `localhost:8000/editclaims/data_ID`. Without number it will not work.

Comment: Yeah it returns with a data ID, I'm unable to submit the data after pressing submit, I've created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67529351/why-does-my-submit-button-renders-a-page-that-is-blank-when-it-is-supposed-to-co

Comment: If you can submit then you forgot `ID` in url in button `submit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your views.py returns the exact path of where the HTML page is, for my case it was Login/editclaims.html

```
def editclaims(request,id):
  context = initialize_context(request)
  user = context['user']
  claims = SaveClaimForm.objects.get(id=id)
  return render(request, "Login/editclaims.html",{'SaveClaimForm':claims, 'user':user})
```