# Why does my Submit button renders a page that is blank when it is supposed to contain the data that was just updated?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to update the values of my database using a HTML Form.

[image]

When I Click Edit it brings me to the edit the values above.

However as I am clicking the submit button, it returns me a database but with no other values.

[image]

Is there anyone that can help me understand what I did wrong and point me to the right documentation (if any)

editclaims.html:

```
<div class="arrange2">
        <h1>Edit Claim Form - #{{claims.id}} </h1>
    </div>
    <form method="POST" action="/update/{{claims.id}}">
        {% csrf_token %}
```

views.py:

```
def editclaims(request,id):
  context = initialize_context(request)
  user = context['user']
  claims = SaveClaimForm.objects.get(id=id)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST['name']
    email = request.POST['email']
    claim = request.POST['claim']
    claimtype = request.POST.get('claimtype')
    description = request.POST['description']
    receipt = request.FILES['receipt']
    cheque = request.POST.get('Cheque')
    form = SaveClaimForm(name=name, email=email, claim=claim, claimtype=claimtype, description=description, receipt=receipt, cheque=cheque)
    form.save()
  
  return render(request, "Login/editclaims.html", {'claims':claims, 'user':user})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('existingclaims/', views.viewclaims, name='existingclaims'),
    path('editclaims/<int:id>', views.editclaims, name='editclaims'),
    path('update/<int:id>', views.updateclaims, name='updateclaims'),
]
```

Comment: What is `initialize_context()` ?

Comment: `initialize_context()` refers to the Microsoft Graph API. It checks for the user in session and check for any errors in the session.

Comment: you don't need both `editclaims` and `updateclaims` but only one of them.

Comment: you runs `claims = ` before `form.save()` so you get old data.

Comment: the right documentation is official django documentation - and you should start it before you even start coding. And you use any other module then first documentation should be this module official documentation. Official documentation often has examples or tutorial or other information.

Comment: @furas I've updated my views.py in the question

Comment: I was confused because I was referring to a youtube video as a reference, thus why I have both `editclaims` and `updateclaims`

Comment: you can use `if request.method == 'POST':` to put all code in one function. If you don't get `POST` then you want to get data from database and display it for editing. If you get `POST` then you clicked `Submit` on page and you have to update data in database and save it.

Comment: I've updated the views.py

Comment: you should use the same name `claims = SaveClaimForm(...)` in both places - instead of `form = ...`. Besides `Form` in you name `SaveClaimForm` is misleading. Django has special class `ModelForm` to build forms in HTML. For data in database I would use name `Claim` without `Form` and without `Save` if you don't have other `Claim` like `EditClaim`, etc.

Comment: in your code you create new `SaveClaimForm` with new data but it will also add new ID so you will have the same data in two rows. You should get original data from database `claims = SaveClaimForm.objects.get(id=id)` and update values `claims.name = request.POST['name']` and later save it `claims.save()` and it will save it with original `ID` - so you will have only one row with this data.

Comment: you may have `MultiValueDictKeyError` because you created new `SaveClaimForm` instead of update existing `SaveClaimForm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not resolve all your problems but it will be more readable as answer.

---

When you get data from HTML then you create new object `SaveClaimForm` and it will have new `ID` and you will have the same object in two rows.

You have to get original `Claim` from database and update values in this object and save it - and then it will save it with original `ID` and you will have only one `object in database

```
def editclaims(request,id):
    context = initialize_context(request)
    user = context['user']

    # get original object     
    claims = SaveClaimForm.objects.get(id=id)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # update original object
        claims.name = request.POST['name']
        claims.email = request.POST['email']
        claims.claim = request.POST['claim']
        claims.claimtype = request.POST.get('claimtype')
        claims.description = request.POST['description']
        claims.receipt = request.FILES['receipt']
        claims.cheque = request.POST.get('Cheque')

        # save it with original `ID`
        claims.save()
      
    return render(request, "Login/editclaims.html", {'claims':claims, 'user':user})
```

---

**BTW:**

`Django` has special class `ModelForm` to create forms in HTML. It may also have methods to check if data in HTML are correct - ie. if fields are not empty, if email is correctly constructed (`name@domain.com`), if phone has only numbers, etc. So using `ModelForm` can be more useful then writing all manually in code.

Comment: How do I implement ModelForm if I were to use Microsoft Graph?

Comment: I never used `Microsoft Graph` - if it is not local database then you should use normal `Form` and write all code from scratch.